Async Constant Call Ignoring Fetch Request
I've bene trying to figure out why an async fetch request gets absolutely ignored  in my reactjs app. Basically, I am calling integrate() which, if generates a successful status result from its internal call, then awaits the result of a secondary async const call fetchOtherStuff()
Integrate is executing without issues, however for some reason Chrome is entirely ignoring the fetch request within fetchOtherStuff.
I know for a fact it is being called, as THIS WILL LOG logs every time. However there is no record of a network request being made and, predictably, THIS WILL NOT LOG does not log.
No console errors, no network requests, almost like it just aborts the call (as well as any other awaited constants below fetchOtherStuff()
Has anyone encountered this before? I don't see anything on S.O.
(Calling await integrate() somewhere)
const integrate = async () => {
  const URL = 'https://whatever-endpoint.com';
  try {
    const response = await fetch(URL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      credentials: 'include'
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      if (response.status === 200) {
        await fetchOtherStuff();
      }
   } catch (error) {
       return {status:500, body: 'Server Error, Please Try Again'}
      }
    }


  const fetchOtherStuff = async () =>{
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
    try {
      console.log("THIS WILL LOG")
      const orgCodes = await fetch(`https://endpoint-whatever.com`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: 'include'
      }); 
      const result = await orgCodes.json();
      console.log("THIS WILL NOT LOG ", result)
      setDomainNotReadyCodes(result)
      resolve(result)               
    } catch (error) {
     reject(error)
    }
  })
}


this is a bit confusing: async function will return a promise, you dont need to explicitly return a promise. Anyway, have you try putting breakpoints into the function?

new Promise(async (resolve,reject) that almost immediately rings alarm bells - also, why would you set a content-type for a GET? GET does not allow a body (in browsers, apparently it is allowed by the specs) so why do you do that?

perhaps const result = await orgCodes.json(); throws/rejects? or even the fetch before it .... try adding console.log(error) in the catch block

I'd suggest a rewrite of the fetchOtherStuff like https://pastebin.com/whrrrijs - note: you don't really need try/catch in there, since you are handling errors in the calling function, but I put that there to troubleshoot your issue

Never pass an async function as the executor to new Promise!
